# I got my printer working. How do I figure out what I did right, so I can reproduce it?

Tags: printing

I was doing all this different stuff (adding/removing PPAs, installing/uninstalling software), trying to get my printer to work. I want to find out what I did right, so that I can do it again, and, more importantly, so that other people can do it. How do I figure out what I did right?

Comment: Err... start for telling us what you did.

Comment: I added and removed a bunch of PPAs. The last three things I ran were:
`sudo apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint`
`sudo restart cups`
`sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp`

Comment: Can you edit your question instead and add that information?

Answer (score 2):

If you used the *command line*, then you can see the last entered commands in the `.bash_history` file located at your home folder (`~`).

---

*I can't think in something else right now. If you know more, feel free to add it here*